# If $(a_n)$ is subsequence of $(b_n)$ and $(b_n)$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, conclude that $(a_n) = (b_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> If $(a_n)$ is subsequence of $(b_n)$ and $(b_n)$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, can we **conclude** that $(a_n) = (b_n)$?

Is their a way I can disprove this? I don't know how I would go about creating two subsequence that are subsequences of one another, and show that they aren't equal.

Comment: Try any two sequences of $0$s and $1$s, with infinitely many $0$s and infinitely many $1$s.

Comment: if I let an = {0,1,0,1,0...} and bn = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...} would that work? would those two be equal?

Comment: What does it mean for two sequences to be equal?  Is each of those a subsequence of the other?

Comment: thats what Im confused on I don't know how to tell..

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ are functions, then $f=g$ if (by definition) for all $x\in X$, $f(x)=g(x)$. Sequences are functions whose domain is $\mathbb N$.  For sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ to be equal means for all $n$, $a_n=b_n$.  For the examples you gave, check if they are equal.  Also, try to see how $(b_n)$ can be expressed as a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple example of such a pair of sequences that are not equal:

$$\begin{align}
\{a_n\} = \{2^n \bmod 11\} &= \{1,2,4,8,5,10,9,7,3,6,1,2,4,\ldots\}\\
\{b_n\} = \{7\cdot2^n \bmod 11\} &= \{7,3,6,1,2,4,8,5,10,9,7,3,6,\ldots\}\\
\end{align}$$

Any such pair of sequences that are non-equal mutual subsequences must have some kind of repetitive nature, if not necessarily cycling of this simple form, since we also have that $\{a_i\}$ is a proper subsequence of itself (and likewise $\{b_i\}$).

Comment: @JonasMeyer good point. updated to soften that conclusion.